# netlify-cli settings ID in Netlify TOML

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cli

I noticed that `netlify-cli` automatically creates a settings ID.

Regarding the ID, the [docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/) say the following:

```
[Settings]
# Added automatically by the Netlify CLI. It has no effect during normal 
# Git-backed deploys.
ID = "Your_Site_ID"
```

I still don't understand why this ID is there. What is the purpose of this ID? Also, can it be committed to a public git repository or is it private?

Thank you for the guidance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID field in netlify.toml is deprecated

The netlify CLI will automatically set your siteID into a ./netlify/state.json file in your project

This is done when running the `netlify link` command